# Get point from line segment that is closest to another point

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 3 points, two of which make up a line segment.

$P_1 = P(1,1)$

$P_2 = P(2,2) \to P(4,1) = P_3$

Now, I want to get the closest point on this line segment to $P(1,1)$. Which is $P(2,2)$.

I know by using $||P_2 - P_1||$ and comparing to $||P_3 - P_1||$ that $P(2,2)$ is the answer.

You can see an example [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1pz2afgeru)

Now if the points are $P_1(1,1)$, $P_2(2,2)$, and $P_3(2,0)$ see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fzontls6lj).

I do not know how to get the correct point which, from my example, should be $P(2,1)$.

Ultimately, I need to determine, if one of the extreme points on the line, $P_2$ or $P_3$ is closest, or if a point on the line $\vec{P_2P_3}$ is closest, and return said closest point as a point to do the rest of my work with.

Comment: The closest point on a *line* to a given point, $P_1$ in this case, lies on the perpendicular from $P_1$ to the line. For a line segment, you should also check whether the perpendicular falls on the line segment

Answer (score 1):

Consider circles centered at $P(1,1)$ of various radii.  If the radius is too small, the circle does not intersect the *line*, $L$, through $P(2,2)$ and $P(4,1)$.  If it is too large, it intersects $L$ twive.  The nearest point on $L$ is the intersection of $L$ with the circle of smallest radius centered at $P(1,1)$ that still intersects $L$.  We should be able to see that, starting with a circle of too large radius, shrinking the radius causes the two intersection points to move towards each other.  The two points coincide at the smallest possible radius and $L$ is tangent to this circle.  This means $L$ is perpendicular to the radius of this circle.

The slope of $L$ is $\frac{2-1}{2-4} = \frac{-1}{2}$.  So the point-slope equation of $L$ is $y - 2 = \frac{-1}{2}(x - 2)$.  The slope of a line perpendicular to this is $-1/(\frac{-1}{2}) = 2$.  Therefore, the line though $P(1,1)$ that intersects $L$ at the point closest to $P(1,1)$ is, using the point-slope form of the line, $y - 1 = 2(x-1)$.

Eliminating $y$ between these, we get
$$ 2 + \frac{-1}{2}(x - 2) = 1 + 2(x-1) $$
from which we conclude $x = 8/5$.  Plugging back into either line, we get $y = 11/5$.

The $x$-coordinates of the endpoints of the desired line segment are $E = \{2,4\}$ and $\min E \leq 8/5 \leq \max E$ is false.  Therefore, the point on $L$ closest to $P(1,1)$ is not inside the line segment.  Consequently, we must find which of $8/5 \leq \min E$ or $\max E \leq 8/5$ is true.  In this case, it is the former, so $P(2,2)$ is the point of the line segment closest to $P(1,1)$.

For your second set of points, the above doesn't work immediately, because the line through $P(2,2)$ and $P(2,0)$ is vertical.  But swapping $x$ and $y$ coordinates, then swapping back works.  Let's use $Q(y,x)$ to remind us that we've swapped coordinates.  You want the closest point to $Q(1,1)$ on the line segment between $Q(0,2)$ and $Q(2,2)$.  The slope of $L$ is $0$ and its equation is $y-2 = 0(x-0)$ (so, $y=2$).  The slope of the perpendicular is vertical (undefined), so the $x$-coordinate of the closest point on $L$ is the same as that of $Q(1,1)$, that is, $1$.  $E = \{0,2\}$ and $\min E \leq 1 \leq \max E$, so the closest point in the line segment is not an endpoint and is $Q(1,2)$.  Switching coordinates back, the closest point is $P(2,1)$.

This general method is

- Find the point-slope equation of $L$ through $P_2$ and $P_3$.  Let $m$ be this slope.  If this slope is undefined (that is, if $P_2$ and $P_3$ have the same $x$-coordinates), swap coordinates.  Remember to swap back at the end.
- Find the point-slope equation of the perpendicular to $L$ through $P_1$.  Use that the slope of this line is $-1/m$.
- Find the intersection of these two lines (only need $x$-coordinate).  Call that $x$.
- Let $E$ be the $x$-coordinates of the points bounding the line segment.
- If $x$ is between these two or equal to either of them, the intersection is on the line segment.  Make the intersection our provisional answer.
  Otherwise, $x$ is not on the line segment.  If $x$ is less than the minimum of $E$, the left endpoint of the segment is our provisional answer.  Otherwise, $x$ is greater than the maximum of $E$ and our provisional answer is the right endpoint of the segment.
- If we are remembering to swap coordinates back at the end, swap the coordinates of our provisional answer.
- The provisional answer is now the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $P_1(1,1)$, $P_2(2,2)$, and $P_3(2,0)$ be three points on a plane. Then all points that lie on the line segment from $P_3$ to $P_2$ are of the form 
$$
\begin{align*}
r(t) &=(2,0) + t \vec{P_3P_2} \\ 
&= (2,0) + t((2,2)-(2,0)) \\ 
&= (2,0) + t(0,2),  
\end{align*}
$$ 
where $0\leq t\leq 1$. 
Now, we want to find the point on this line segment that is closest to the point $P_1$. 
So we want to minimize the distance function 
$$
d(t) = || r(t)-P_1||,   
$$
which is equivalent to minimizing the function 
$$
f(t) = || r(t)-P_1||^2. 
$$
Since 
$$
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= ||(2,0) + t(0,2)-(1,1) ||^2 \\ 
&= ||(1,-1)+(0,2t) ||^2 \\  
&= || (1, 2t-1) ||^2 \\ 
&= 1^2 + (2t-1)^2 \\ 
&= 4t^2 -4t + 2, \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
we have 
$$
f'(t) = 8t -4. 
$$
Set $f'(t)=0$ to find all local min and local max. We see that $t=\frac{1}{2}$. 
By calculating $f''(t)=8 >0$, we see that $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is a local min and that $r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= (2,0)+ \frac{1}{2}(0,2) = (2,1)$. 
Now considering the boundary points $P_2$ and $P_3$ as well, since

- $|| \vec{P_1P_2} || = \sqrt{2}$,
- $|| \vec{P_1P_3} || = \sqrt{2}$, and
- $|| \vec{P_1 r\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}|| =1$,

$r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is the point on the line segment that is closest to $P_1$.

Comment: I am trying to implement your math in a more general way, as such I am testing it on desmos using https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ylnuihihmr Which appears to be close. However, I am not getting the correct point.

Comment: @Drew I will reply back later. I am not in front of a computer.

Comment: No rush, I am implementing the other answer and it seems to be working. But I am still curious because from what I am reading in your answer should work as well. Given I am implementing this in python using numpy using linear algebra would be more efficient.

Comment: @Drew on the desmos graph, if you multiply t by 2, you get the right answer.
Here's a working version: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qbtyssnnmf